# laravel + vue count number of views

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I have an articles site based on Laravel and Vue, I want to count the number of visits for each article (when the user opens the article the number of visits increases by one), in Laravel I used the eloquent-viewable package, but with Laravel + Vue I don't know how to do it.

can you help me please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this approach

**in your mount event register this function**

```
mounted() {
        
        this.view();
    },
methods: {
        view() {
            axios.get('/home/food_view/' + this.$route.params.id).then((response) => {
                if (response.data.error)
                    Toast.fire({
                        icon: 'error',
                        title: response.data.error,
                    })
            });
        },
    }
```

**and in your migration create a column**

```
$table->integer('view')->default(0);
```

**and then in your controller do something like that**

```
$model = Model::find($id);
$model->view += 1;
$model->save();
```

**update you can use these route in route.js**

```
{
                path: '/food_details/:id/:slug',
                name: 'food_details',
                component: foodDetails
            },
```

Comment: Can you write how the Route should be in the API file please?